# How to prevent a specific method call from an external library

Tags: c#

we are using a 3rd party library (ORM Mapper) to access a database. This library has no support anymore.
Short time ago we found some bug in a specific method in this library (it crashes when it gets not-unique entities in a list to save in the database) and I implemented a C# extension class where this bug is fixed, an I also found and replaced all calls for a library method with my extension and communicated this issue with my team.

Now I want to prevent using of library method in our code base, so it's only an extension class call permitted. How can I ensure nobody can use a library method in the future or at least he will be notified that this call is prohibited.

I took a look on ReSharper's External Annotations, but did not found it useful in my case.

Comment: Have you considered writing a Roslyn analyzer to spot calls to the method?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is to write a unit test that uses something like NDepend or Roslyn to find usages of the method call.

Comment: Is it an option to modify the library (ildasm -> patch -> ilasm)? Then you could mark this method as `[Obsolete]`, remove it, rename it or let it throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a small custom code analyzer based on "Analyzer with Code Fix" Microsoft's template and then added resulting dll in our project, so me and my teammates can use it. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx) article helped me a lot.